# How to activate the AMD GPU manually?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

i have some trouble with my Intel/AMD-GPU-Setup.

I am using a laptop with an "Intel Core i3-2350M 'Sandy Bridge'", which has the build-in iGPU "Intel HD 3000". In addition to this iGPU my laptop has the dGPU "AMD Radeon HD 6490M".

A few weeks ago i changed my system from Linux Mint 17.3 (Ubuntu 14.04-LTS-based, Kernel 3.19 with proprietary fglrx-driver) to Linux Mint 18.0 (Ubuntu 16.04-LTS-based, Kernel 4.4.0 with open-source radeon-driver).

With this new version of Mint/Ubuntu the AMD proprietary fglrx-driver with Catalyst Control Center is not supported and installable anymore and the dGPU is too old for the new amdgpu-driver. So my system is running on the radeon-driver now.

With the fglrx-driver and Catalyst Control Center i was able to activate and deactivate the AMD dGPU, depending on my use-cases, manually.
With the radeon-driver now it's a bit different.

When i check my current GPU state with

```
$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

the result is always

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

This means, that the iGPU is active and the dGPU is deactivated (by software/driver).
Since i have (like all modern laptops) a muxless device, the entry 0:IGD looks good, but 1:DIS should change its state, when needed, to something like this

```
1:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0
```

I found on this post

[How to disable my APU and use the GPU (AMD Radeon) open source driver instead?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549137/how-to-disable-my-apu-and-use-the-gpu-amd-radeon-open-source-driver-instead?rq=1)

that i can force to use the AMD dGPU with a specific application (i.e. glxgears) like this

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears
```

but not as the default GPU, used by the whole system (like with the Catalyst Control Center). Is this even possible (yet) with the open-source radeon-driver?
And is there a way to use something like auto-GPU-switching (like, when the Intel iGPU has reached maximum load, the AMD dGPU will automatically be switched on) ?

Greetings and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
```